# What is the logic for solving this sequence?

Tags: algorithm, logic

The sequence goes like this.. `7,8,77,78,87,88,777,778,787,788` and so on..

What can be the logic for finding the nth number of the sequence? I tried that by dividing it by 2 and then by 4 and hence, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: People who vote to close it: how is algorithm for finding n-th element of sequence is off-topic?

Comment: It'd be nice if people commented but if i had to guess it's that it smells like homework and a complete answer rather than a hint is being asked for.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: It doesn't make sense to have a n-th element algorithm. Any sequence can continue in any way.

Comment: Consider this sequence: [0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 000, 001, 010, 011]. It's the same as yours.

Comment: @Thomas: It does seem to have a certain similarity, but that doesn't really explain the reason to close.  What about that sequence is unworthy of being in a question?

Comment: moreover i didn't ask for a complete answer.. i just asked for logic.. it's coder's generosity that they provided me with the code too.. thanks a lot..

Comment: @recursive: I'm sorry if it seamed like I were in favour of closing. I remember the founders of SO saying, that anything the community finds interesting is relevant. And I think this questions is interesting.

Comment: I have voted to close as Not A Real Question.

Comment: Although an accepted answer has been picked, I've cast the last reopen vote because I don't see the OT-ness of this question.

Comment: @BoltClock: You realize both On- and Off- start with O, right? :)

Comment: @Roger: LOL, good point, of course I meant "off-topic-ness" ;)

Comment: @bmargulies: Not just non-programming, this isn't a real question with specific answers. "What is the next term in the sequence" type questions are bogus questions with no single right answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Observations:**

1. The sequence appears to be an ascending list of numbers containing only the digits 7 and 8.
2. The number of digits is non-decreasing and for each n-digit section, there are `2 ** n` numbers in the sequence.
3. The first half of the n-digit numbers starts with 7, and the second half starts with 8.
4. For each half of the n-digit numbers, the remaining digits after the first are the same as the n-1 digit numbers.

These facts can be used to construct a reasonably efficient recursive implementation.

Here is a C# implementation:

```
void Main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Console.WriteLine (GetSequence(i));
}

string GetSequence(int idx) {
    if (idx == 0) return "7";
    if (idx == 1) return "8";

    return GetSequence(idx / 2 - 1) + GetSequence(idx % 2);
}
```

Output:

```
7
8
77
78
87
88
777
778
787
788
```

Comment: seems you are obsessed with recursion.. :)

Answer (score 22):

Binary, counting from two, ignoring the leading digit, using 7 and 8 for zero and one:

```
        7,  8,  77,  78,  87,  88,  777,  778,  787,  788
 0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011
```

Comment: +1 for the solution. Wonderful observation Pete! Here is the python 2.6 implementation -for i in range(2,15):print "".join(map((lambda x: ('8','7')[x=='0']), bin(i)[2:])[1:]),

Comment: Bloated. Here: `for i in range(2,15):print"".join('78'[int(x)]for x in bin(i)[3:]),`

Answer (score 4):

Since size of block is growing exponentially (2 elements of length 1, 4 elements of length 2, 8 elements of length 3, etc), you can easily determine number of digits in result number.

```
    long block_size = 2;
    int len = 1;
    while (n > block_size) {
        n -= block_size;  // n is changed here
        block_size *= 2;
        ++len;
    }
```

Now, you just create binary representation of `n - 1`, with 7 for zeroes and 8 for ones (padding it to length `len` with zeroes). Quite simple.

I assume indexes start from 1 here.

Comment: lets take n=10.. that must give 788 as answer.. or 011. but for n=10, n-1 is 9 which gives the binary sequence of 1001.. taking the block size as 3 we select last three binaries i.e. 001 which is not the answer..!!

Comment: @vaibhav Note, we change _n_ in the loop too. I edited answer to emphasize it.

Answer (score 2):

substitute 0 for 7 and 1 for 8 and treat it like a binary sequence

Comment: Not exactely: 7* = 0* will always be 0.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a simple binary sequence, where 7 represents binary zero, and 8 represents binary 1.

Comment: ok.. then why the third number is 77 or in your case.. 00..??

Comment: The sequence restarts at binary zero, but with two digits instead of one. And so on.  Each time the sequence overflows its digits, restart at zero and add another digit.

Comment: The problem is to find the nth element, and that would require enumerating all elements until n.

Comment: @recursive: Not really.  `d = 1; seq = n; while (seq >= 2^d) { seq -= 2^d; ++d; }`.  You'll be returning the `seq`'th `d`-digit sequence, which turns trivially into the required sequence by converting 0 into 7 and 1 into 8.

Answer (score 2):

Written as PHP. I assume that the sequence elements are numbered starting from 1.

```
$n = 45;
// let's find the 45th sequence element.
$length = 1;
while ( $n >= pow(2, $length + 1) - 1 ) {
    $length++;
}
// determine the length in digits of the sequence element
$offset = $n - pow(2, $length) + 1;
// determine how far this sequence element is past the
// first sequence element of this length
$binary = decbin($offset);
// obtain the binary representation of $offset, as a string of 0s and 1s
while ( strlen($binary) < $length ) {
    $binary = '0'.$binary;
}
// left-pad the string with 0s until it is the required length
$answer = str_replace( array('0', '1'),
                       array('7', '8'),
                       $binary
                       );
```

Comment: +1: Looks like we had the same idea. ;) You can actually avoid the first while loop by using the [log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php) and [floor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) functions.

Comment: Yes, I considered log() and floor(), but I wasn't sure whether floor() would cause problems due to floating-point inaccuracy in php.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute this *directly* for the Nth number (`num`) *without recursion or looping* by doing the following (the sample code is in MATLAB):

- Compute the number of digits in the number:

  ```
  nDigits = floor(log2(num+1));
  ```
- Find the binary representation of the number `num` (only the first `nDigits` digits) after first subtracting one less than two raised to the power `nDigits`:

  ```
  binNum = dec2bin(num-(2^nDigits-1),nDigits);
  ```
- Add 7 to each value in the string of ones and zeroes:

  ```
  result = char(binNum+7);
  ```

And here's a test, putting the above three steps into one anonymous function `f`:

```
>> f = @(n) char(dec2bin(n+1-2^floor(log2(n+1)),floor(log2(n+1)))+7);
>> for n = 1:20, disp(f(n)); end
7
8
77
78
87
88
777
778
787
788
877
878
887
888
7777
7778
7787
7788
7877
7878
```